# Protocol Buffer Make command not found libprotobuf.dll.a

Tags: c++, makefile, protocol-buffers, gnu-make

I downloaded the protocolbuffer-2.5.0.zip file,
then i follow the Readme.txt installion:

```
./configure
make
make check
make install
```

and in command make i get an error message: 
"g++.exe: error: /cygdrive/d/BayProject/protobuf-2.5.0/src/.libs/libprotobuf.dll.                                                                                                                a: No such file or directory"

But the file libprotobuf.dll.a is there!

What do i wrong? 
Thx

Answer (score 0):

Do you have gcc/mingw installed for Cygwin64? I had this same issue then realized it was configuring with my Perl64 gcc compiler. Installing the Cygwin version from setup.exe allowed protobuf to build and pass all tests.